# Execute exe which needs input file in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

Is there any way to run exe with inputs in Python?
For example, there are two files, aaa.exe and bbb.dat. To run the analysis, I need to put those two files on DOS prompt like below. aaa.exe read the bbb.dat file. It there any command or workaround for this? I tried os.system and subprocess but I could not find a solution...

c:\Users\Program\Siimulation\Input> aaa.exe \bbb.dat

os.system("aaa.exe", "bbb.dat")

Comment: `os.system(r"aaa.exe \bbb.dat")`

Answer (score 0):

You can o it by argparse. You can mark an argument as required by passing required=True to add_argument.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument("foo", ..., required=True)
parser.parse_args()
```

or you can use "sys"

```
import sys
len( sys.argv ) > 1
```